# Problem with gmapping and rviz: "No map received" & "Fixed frame [map] does not exist"

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run the [map-building tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) with gmapping and rviz. However I get some errors that I **did not get before** (and I do not recall changing anything significant).

First of all, it says, "**No map received**", even though the right topics are subscribed to and the status of each topic is *OK* (see attached image file).

Secondly, under Global Options, the Fixed Frame, by default, is set to *map*. The Global Status then goes on to say that this **frame does not exist**, when, clearly, according to the tf-tree produced by *rosrun tf view frames*, it **does**!

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Specifications: ROS Distribution - Hydro; OS Distribution - Ubuntu 13.04 Raring.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145796/problem-with-gmapping-and-rviz:-%22no-map-received%22-&-%22fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist%22/) by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind. My problem was that, though I was running rviz on my workstation, ROS_MASTER_URI on my .bashrc file was set to **my** workstation's IP, **not** my turtlebot's -_- Very silly error.

---

Originally posted by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) with karma: 105 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1